# How to Display a List of New Users on Site Page

Tags: 2013, development, data-view-web-part, user-accounts, sitepages

I would like to create a page on our SharePoint site which displays a list of all users which have been recently added to the site.

This page will also have a few other bits, such as a new user's events calendar and maybe a discussion board.

My main goal though, is to create a list which will always contain all users which were recently added, and then display this list on the page (I am guessing this will be done as a web part).

[This page](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/bambooteamblog/archive/2013/02/04/how-to-show-the-all-people-view-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx) had some useful information on how to access a list of all users, but I couldn't work out how to filter this into new users only and then add those users to a list.

Does anyone have any advice on how to achieve this, or whether it is even possible?

I have had a look at the "secret" user list which can be at `MySite/_catalogs/users/simple.aspx`, but I am not sure how to manipulate this data, as it doesn't appear to be a normal list and I can't select `Edit Page` on that view to investigate the List.

---

**Update**

My current plan is as follows :

- Get all "new" users using the `item["Created"]` variable
- Add these users to an excel spreadsheet
- Use some more code to add the users in the spreadsheet to both a group (which I will grant permission to view the new user page), and a custom list
- This list will be displayed on the New Users page
- More code to remove and users which are now "old" from both the list, spreadsheet and permissions group

This is the only way I can think of doing this at the moment, and would really appreciate some feedback / suggestions on how this can best be achieved.

Thank you

Comment: Have you considered using the hidden user-list? /_catalogs/users/simple.aspx

Comment: @Nils Thanks for your comment, I have had a look at that but not sure how I can use it. for example, I would like to use that as a  data source for a new, custom list (as this sounds more reasonable than my idea above with the spreadsheets), but I have no idea where to start with this. That hidden user page has no `Edit Page` option and I can't seem to connect to it in C#, as I don't have the name for that list (note my current solution uses `SPWeb.AllUsers`)

Comment: I fear the actual datetimes for when a user was added to a site will only be available through audit data... as mentioned here: https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2013/07/06/querying-the-sharepoint-audit-log-for-group-membership-changes-of-a-specific-user/